# is there a known issue with pandas merging two data frames that each have an index of type datetime

Tags: pandas

I am merging two data frames that each have an index of type datetime and getting as result a data frame with more rows than the two original.
The two data frames have the same number of records each and the same values of the index.
When taking a look - I see that there are duplicate records on the same index - is it a known issue ?

the code:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Can you share how the two dataframes are created?

Comment: I am reading two csv files with a datetime separately, loading then to data frames and then setting the datetime as an index for each. I checked and saw that the values of the datetime are identical before merging

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to datetime indices. The reason for the merged dataframe having more rows than either of the original ones is that when the merge key (here: the datetime index) values are not unique, the merge algorithm falls back on the cross product style join for the repeated values, regardless of which join type you specify.

However, if I understand you correctly, using `merge` is overkill here anyway, because you just want to concatenate the two dataframes:

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I have checked this - and the values of the index for both data frames are unique

Comment: Okay, I must have misread your sentence about duplicate records, thinking you were referring to the input dataframes. Could you post samples of the two input dataframes that allow reproducing the effect of the merge producing additional rows?